# R: Subtracting a Subgraph from a Graph

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following network graph:

```
# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate a vector of ID's from 1 to 100
ids <- 1:100

# Initialize an empty data frame to store the "from" and "to" values
edges <- data.frame(from=integer(), to=integer(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Iterate through the ID's
for(id in ids) {
    # Randomly select a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 8 neighbors for the current ID
    neighbors <- sample(ids[ids != id], size=sample(1:8, size=1))
    
    # Add a new row to the data frame for each "to" value
    for(neighbor in neighbors) {
        edges <- rbind(edges, data.frame(from=id, to=neighbor))
    }
}


library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)


# Convert the data frame to an igraph object
original_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed=FALSE)
```

[image]

**I am trying to accomplish the following procedure:**

- Step 1: Randomly select a "starting_node" from the "original_graph"
- Step 2: Randomly select a "radius" (i.e. degree) between 0 and 3
- Step 3: Randomly select nodes connected to the "starting_node" within the original graph (call this "sub-graph") of this random "radius"
- Step 4: "Subtract" the "sub-graph" from the "original_graph"

Here is my attempt to start this problem:

```
# step 1:
starting_node <- sample(V(original_graph), 1)$name

# step 2:
radius <- sample(0:3, 1)

# step 3:
neighbors <- induced.subgraph(original_graph, unlist(ego(original_graph, order=radius, nodes=starting_node)))
```

**But from here - I am not sure how to randomly build the subgraph around the starting_node and then subtract the resulting subgraph from the original_graph.**

Can someone please show me how to continue this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could subtract the names of the `neighbors` graph from the `original_graph` and then use the `induced.subgraph` function to create the desired graph. I'm not quite sure what you mean in step 3 when randomly selecting nodes but perhaps you could repeat your `sample` call but this time from the `neighbors` graph. EDIT - I added some code to do this.

```
vids <- unlist(ego(original_graph, order=radius, nodes=starting_node))
neighbors <- induced.subgraph(original_graph, vids = vids)
# find the names of the neighbors excluding the starting node
neighbor_names <- setdiff(V(neighbors)$name, starting_node)
# choose some random names - this won't work if the number of nodes is less than this - 3 for this example
random_neighbor_names <- sample(neighbor_names, 3)
# make a graph from the sampled names and the original
random_neighbors <- induced.subgraph(original_graph, vids=c(starting_node, random_neighbor_names))
# calculate the difference between the original and the random neighbors
remaining_names <- setdiff(V(original_graph)$name, V(random_neighbors)$name)
remaining <- induced.subgraph(original_graph, vids = remaining_names)
```

Comment: @ Andrew Chisholm: Thank you for your answer! What I am looking to do is build a random subgraph from a random node. For example - consider a network with a group of friends. I randomly pick a node (e.g. john) - I then randomly pick a radius (e.g. degree = 3) - then, I randomly pick a number of neighbors (e.g. 5). In the end - I would build a subgraph of 5 neighbors of john connected to john by at most 3 degrees. Does this make sense?

Comment: @ Andrew Chisholm: Thank you so much for your edits! I posted a related question here where I tried to outline the problem a bit more clearly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75599439/r-writing-graph-based-functions ... can you please take a look at it if you have time? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subgraph` or `induced.subgraph` (as [Andrew Chisholm did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75590087/12158757))

```
original_graph %>%
  subgraph(!V(.) %in% unlist(ego(., order = radius, nodes = starting_node)))
```

Comment: @ ThomasIsCoding: Thank you so much for your answer! What I am looking to do is build a random subgraph from a random node. For example - consider a network with a group of friends. I randomly pick a node (e.g. john) - I then randomly pick a radius (e.g. degree = 3) - then, I randomly pick a number of neighbors (e.g. 5). In the end - I would build a subgraph of 5 neighbors of john connected to john by at most 3 degrees. Does this make sense?

Comment: @stats_noob I think you are almost there. For example, you can pick 5 random vertices from `ego` (with radius `3`) , then subset the graph based on those 5 vertices.

Comment: Thank you! I posted a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75599439/r-writing-graph-based-functions  - I am trying to apply your logic to such a question

Comment: @stats_noob yes, see my answer there